# How to create setup file for WPF core 3.1 with setup installer in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, deployment

Dears,

I developed wpf core 3.1 app and want to create installer file, so I use setup installer with visual studio 2019.

this tool create setup file correctly, but when install new setup I got my app as DLL not exe

can anyone help me to get exe file

thanks

Comment: We use the installer project plugin to create distributables for our game suite. There's no difference between net core and net old other than you won't find the core framework available to choose as a dependency.

Comment: Depending on how you "publish" the application, you may get a dll instead of a exe.  You then call 'dotnet <name of assembly> to launch it.  What does your publish profile look like?

Comment: you can use [1 file which contains everything](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/06/20/publishing-a-single-exe-file-in-net-core-3-0/) and copy it to other devices

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys, I solve this issue with add the output of publish files in setup project and create setup file direct